# Java split sentence into a multi dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I currently have a multidimensional array with 5 columns that gets its elements filled via a sentence from another array (names array) My problem is that everything is getting stored in the first column. For example,

```
word[][] = [25  Jackson 11,693   Nevaeh     6,345] [] [] [] []
```

However I want it to get stored like this

```
word[][] = [25][Jackson][11,693][Nevaeh][6,455]
```

.

```
        String [] names = topNames.toArray(new String[topNames.size()]);
        String[][] words = new String[names.length][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length(); j++){
                words[i][0] = names[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                System.out.println(words[i][0]);
        }
```

Comment: The pattern is not really clear.

Comment: Based on the example above, you're wanting to split a string at each space? If so, then you can do `string.split(" ")`, which will return an array with each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
String[] names = new String[]{
        "25 Jackson 11,693 Nevaeh 6,345",
        "26 Jackson 44,444 Nevaeh 3,56"
};
String[][] words = new String[names.length][5];

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    words[i] = names[i].split("\\s+");
}

Arrays.stream(words).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And why not use `Collections` instead of arrays?

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(
        "25 Jackson 11,693 Nevaeh 6,345",
        "26 Jackson 44,444 Nevaeh 3,56"
);

List<List<String>> words = names.stream()
        .map(sentence -> sentence.split("\\s+"))
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

words.forEach(System.out::println);
```